# How to put one Card on top of another in a 3d stack?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styling

I was wondering how can emulate Tinder's swipe cards mechanism by getting my cards representing each user's information to be fixed in a single position overlapping one another completely so that the only visible one is the one on top until you swipe it away.

I have used the react-tinder-card library to implement the swiping mechanism, however I don't understand how to get these cards to stay on top of one another so the next one becomes visible when swiped.

Currently, they are positioned in a 2d tower/column and when the top is swiped, after about 3 seconds, the below cards all move up by one:

[image]

OnSwipe:

[image]

Swiped:

[image]

Code:

```
export const SwipeCard = () => {

    //array of compatible users fetched for a user.
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [lastDirection, setLastDirection] = useState()
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getUsers().then(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        });
    }, []);

    const swiped = (direction, nameToDelete) => {
        console.log('removing: ' + nameToDelete)
        setLastDirection(direction)
    }

    const outOfFrame = (firstName) => {
        console.log(firstName + ' left the screen!')
    }

    const getUsers = async () => {
        //Currently hardcoded value until authorisation implemented.
        const userId = 7;
        
        const response = await UserService.getUsers(userId)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    users[i] = data[i];
                }
            });
    }

    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <div/>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div id='tinderCards'>
                {lastDirection ? <h2 className='text'>You swiped {lastDirection}</h2> : <h2 className='text' />}
            {users.map((user) =>
                <TinderCard className='swipeCard' key={user.firstName} onSwipe={(dir) => swiped(dir, user.firstName)} onCardLeftScreen={() => outOfFrame(user.firstName)}>
                    <div className='card'>
                        <img id='profileImg' src={config.URL + '/users/' + user.userID + '/image/download'} />
                        <h2>{user.firstName} {user.lastName}</h2>
                    </div>
                </TinderCard>
            )}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The closest I have been able to come was by setting the parent to position = relative, and then the children cards to position = absolute, but then they all overlap one another, making it unreadable, and also they are stacked in reverse order, so Nike Tyson was on the top when he should've been at the bottom.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use an animation library like framer-motion for this. I've seen this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-tinder-card-swipe-gesture-using-react-and-framer-motion/) that you can maybe follow.